# matplotlib ImportError: cannot import name 'style'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Windows 10, install python 3.5, pip install matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib as mlt
mlt.__version__
'1.5.1'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get following error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 30, in <module>
    from matplotlib import style
ImportError: cannot import name 'style'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably due to the way you installed matplotlib. In my experience `pip install matplotlib` does not work.

I would try the Windows installer from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib. There are both 32-bit and 64-bit  builds for Python 3.5 version there.

Comment: My windows is x64
c:\Python\Python35-32>Scripts\pip install c:\matplotlib-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
matplotlib-1.5.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
wtf?